# Check if string is substring of any element in jsonb array in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a column of type `jsonb` in a Postgres database. How do I check if a string is a substring of any element in the jsonb array? Ideally, the solution would also ignore capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
with cte as (
  select jsonb_array_elements('["hello", "world", "earth", "universe"]') as word
  from test
) 
select cte.word, position('wor' in cte.word::text) > 0 "isSubstr" 
from cte;
```

Comment: What is `cte` and what is `test`. I'm guessing test is the table containing the `jsonb` column, but what is `cte`?

Comment: @Roymunson indeed such details, sample data should be shared in the question ...